# Could Matlab use system time as X axis value?

Tags: matlab, time, plot

I have a 3D camera that could give Matlab information about the distance of an object in real time after the command `distance=function1(Device)`(I have omit this function since it is not important here).

I would like to make a program that shows the object moving when time changes.

I have already succeeded in using:

```
t1=clock;

while......(in a loop) 
  distance(i)=step(Device);
  t2=clock;
  times(i)=etime(t2,t1);
  plot(times,distance);
end
```

to show the object moving. However, the X axis in this figure is the comparative time, which means the x axis begins with 0 seconds and ends with (t2-t1) seconds .

Now I try to find a way to change the X axis to the absolute time or the cpu time.
Like the following picture:

[image]

I'd like to change the comparative time(in black fonts) to the absolute system time (in red fonts).

I have try ' datetick' but it doesn't work properly?
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following creates a string out of the clock, plots distance, then attempts to change the labels based on the text strings each iteration. I tested a simple instance of it in MATLAB.

```
while ... (in a loop)
    distance(i)=step(Device);
    t2=clock;
    tint = int8(t2(4:6)))
    stamp{i} = strcat(int2str(tint(1)),':',int2str(tint(2)),':',int2str(tint(3)))
    plot(distance)
    set(gca,'XTick',1:i,'XTickLabel',stamp)
end
```

As far as getting the AM and PM to show, well, you'll have to do some extra witchcraft but it should be possible, based on the clock values. Then just append AM or PM into the `stamp{i}` assignation.

Hint, if `t2(4) > 12` you are looking at PM. Else, AM.

One limitation with this is that the more iterations you do, the more crowded your X-Axis is going to become.